# Firebase Auth Signout Error - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, ios10, xcode8-beta2

When I try to sign out the user using this method, I just get an error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred while
>   accessing the keychain." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error
>   occurred while accessing the keychain.,
>   error_name=ERROR_KEYCHAIN_ERROR,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemDelete (-34018)}: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.33.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 146

```
func logout() {
    try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
}
```

I didn't find anything on the web addressing this error.. does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: What is on your line number 146?

Comment: try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the Keychain Sharing entitlement.

From the Project Navigator, go to your project settings and find your target. Under the Capabilities tab, turn on Keychain Sharing.

I had the same problem trying to create a new user. I'm not sure exactly why Firebase needs this permission now, but it works.